# Pass style array to React Component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, css-modules

I want to pass an array of styles to a React Component using postcss-loader and css modules. My webpack.config.file for compiling css files looks like this:

```
loaders: [
    'style-loader', 
    'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    'postcss-loader'
],
```

My React Component file looks like this:

```
import styles from './cssFile.css';
class Component extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return(
           <div className={[styles.spinner, styles.spinner_2]}></div>
       )
    }   
}
```

Whenever I pass only one style to className it loads it correctly but when I pass an array it does not resolve any of them. Instead it concatenates it with a comma on the compile class name.

How can I pass several styles to an element?

Comment: It might just be in the code you've pasted in SO but your class syntax is invalid, you need to define a render method and return the React element. Other than that @ori-drori is correct in saying className must be a string.

Answer (score 6):

React's className expects a string of class names, and not an array:

```
import styles from './cssFile.css';
class Component extends React.Component{
    <div className={ [styles.spinner, styles.spinner_2].join(' ') }></div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) for this. For example:

```
import styles from './cssFile.css';
import classNames from 'classnames';

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className={classNames(styles.spinner, styles.spinner_2)}></div>
  }
}
```

From the classnames documentation:

> The classNames function takes any number of arguments which can be a
>   string or object. If the value of the key is falsy, it won't be
>   included in the output.